# Locals depends_on - Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a `module a` in terraform which creates a `text` file , i need to use that text file in another `module b`, i am using `locals` to pull the content of that text file like below in `module b`

```
locals {
   ports = split("\n", file("ports.txt") ) 
 }
```

But the `terraform` expects this file to be present at the start itself, throws error as below

```
Invalid value for "path" parameter: no file exists at
path/ports.txt; this function works only with files
that are distributed as part of the configuration source code, so if this file
will be created by a resource in this configuration you must instead obtain
this result from an attribute of that resource.
```

What am i missing here? Any help on this would be appreciated. Is there any `depends_on` for `locals`, how can i make this work

Comment: How do you use the two modules? Do you have any complete code to show demonstrating the issue?

Comment: Apologies if this isn't a real answer. Terraform is very good at figuring out dependencies along it's graph - if you're writing to the filesystem and then reading that file, you're punching out of the graph, and jumping back in. If you can do it inside the graph, you're going to have a better time. Can module a pass the information out to module b rather than passing via filesystem?

Answer (score 2):

Modules are called from within other modules using module blocks. Most arguments correspond to **input variables** defined by the module. To reference the value from one module, you need to declare the output in that module, then you can call the output value from other modules.

For example, I suppose you have a text file in module a.

.tf file in module a

```
output "textfile" {
    value = file("D:\\Terraform\\modules\\a\\ports.txt")
}
```

.tf file in module b

```
variable "externalFile" {   
}

locals {
   ports = split("\n", var.externalFile) 
 }


#  output "b_test" {
#      value = local.ports
#  }
```

.tf file in the root module

```
module "a" {
    source = "./modules/a"
}

module "b" {
  source              = "./modules/b"

  externalFile   = module.a.textfile
  depends_on = [module.a]
}


# output "module_b_output" {
#   value = module.b.b_test
# }
```

For more reference, you could read https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/syntax.html#accessing-module-output-values

Comment: This does not work, because it expects `output "textfile" {
    value = file("D:\\Terraform\\modules\\a\\ports.txt")
}` this file to be present at the start, same error

Comment: This is an example. How do you generate a text file in module a? You just need to pass the text file value to an output variable in the original module a.

Comment: `module a` generates a `text file`  in a `folder` through a `bash script`, `module b` needs to use it.

Comment: it says `Invalid value for "path" parameter: no file exists at
path/ports.txt', but it will get created only after we run the `terraform apply`

Comment: Could you please show the section code about the module a generate a text file in a folder through a bash script?

Answer (score 1):

As the error message reports, the `file` function is only for files that are included on disk as part of your configuration, *not* for files generated dynamically during the apply phase.

I would typically suggest avoiding writing files to local disk as part of a Terraform configuration, because one of Terraform's main assumptions is that any objects you manage with Terraform will persist from one run to the next, but that could only be true for a local file if you always run Terraform in the same directory on the same computer, or if you use some other more complex approach such as a network filesystem. However, since you didn't mention *why* you are writing a file to disk I'll assume that this is a hard requirement and make a suggestion about how to do it, even though I would consider it a last resort.

[The `hashicorp/local` provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local) includes a data source called [`local_file`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/data-sources/file) which will read a file from disk in a similar way to how a more typical data source might read from a remote API endpoint. In particular, it will respect any dependencies reflected in its configuration and defer reading the file until the apply step if needed.

You could coordinate this between modules then by making the output value which returns the filename also depend on whichever resource is responsible for creating the file. For example, if the file were created using a provisioner attached to an `aws_instance` resource then you could write something like this inside the module:

```
output "filename" {
  value      = "D:\\Terraform\\modules\\a\\ports.txt"
  depends_on = [aws_instance.example]
}
```

Then you can pass that value from one module to the other, which will carry with it the implicit dependency on `aws_instance.example` to make sure the file is actually created first:

```
module "a" {
  source = "./modules/a"
}

module "b" {
  source = "./modules/b"

  filename = module.a.filename
}
```

Then finally, inside the module, declare that input variable and use it as part of the configuration for a `local_file` data resource:

```
variable "filename" {
  type = string
}

data "local_file" "example" {
  filename = var.filename
}
```

Elsewhere in your second module you can then use `data.local_file.example.content` to get the contents of that file.

Notice that dependencies propagate automatically aside from the explicit `depends_on` in the `output "filename"` block. It's a good practice for a module to encapsulate its own behaviors so that everything needed for an output value to be useful has already happened by the time a caller uses it, because then the rest of your configuration will just get the correct behavior by default without needing any additional `depends_on` annotations.

But if there is any way you can return the data inside that `ports.txt` file directly from the first module instead, without writing it to disk at all, I would recommend doing that as a more robust and less complex approach.